# Assign values from a list to a multivariable function that also has other arguments

Tags: list-manipulation, multivalued

I am new to Mathematica's way of programming. I have a multivariable function, part of whose values are available as a list, and the remaining in another list. To illustrate, I will present my problem with an MRE.

I have a function that is defined as follows:

```
func[x_,y_,z_,m_,n_]:=(3x+4y+z)/(2m+n)
```

I have a list of values for `x,y,z`:

```
listxyz = {{1,1,1},{1,1,2},{1,1,3},{1,2,1},{1,2,2},{1,2,3},{1,3,1},{1,3,2},{1,3,3},{2,1,1},{2,1,2},{2,1,3},{2,2,1},{2,2,2},{2,2,3},{2,3,1},{2,3,2},{2,3,3},{3,1,1},{3,1,2},{3,1,3},{3,2,1},{3,2,2},{3,2,3},{3,3,1},{3,3,2},{3,3,3}}
```

and another list of `m,n`:

```
listmn = {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{2,1},{2,2},{2,3},{3,1},{3,2},{3,3}}
```

where I want to evaluate this function for all possible combinations of elements from `listxyz` and `listmn`.

(Note that this is a minimum reproducible example, and so the lists are smaller and less complicated than my actual case, where I have ~10-15 variables and each list has ~50-60 entries).

If all I had was a function of `x,y,z` I could use the `Apply` on `func` and my list to get the desired answer. How do I do this for my case where there are more terms?

Edit : Added values for the lists for ease of answering, and to clarify the question further

Comment: Can you please provide a short example of these two lists? Do you want this function to evaluate only for each pair of elements of the two lists, or for all possible pairs of the two?

Comment: I've edited the question, and I've added example lists. I want to evaluate for all possible pairs of elements from these two lists.

Comment: `listxyz` and `listmn` are different lengths. If they were the same length, we could align them and thread through them. Since they're different lengths, how do you want to combine them?

Comment: @lericr I'd like to evaluate it for all possible pairs of elements from listxyz and listmn. So that would mean 27x9=243 outputs

Comment: Is there no equivalent of Python's unpack feature `*list_name` in Mathematica? Life would be a lot easier that way.

Comment: @haricash, the equivalent is to use `Sequence`. For example: `f[Sequence @@ {1, 2, 3}]` gives `f[1, 2, 3]`.

Answer (score 5):

Let's simplify even more to help clarify. If our input lists were the same length, say,

```
listxyz = {{1, 2, 3}, {4, 5, 6}, {7, 8, 9}};
listmn = {{10, 11}, {12, 13}, {14, 15}};
```

then we could do something like this:

```
Apply[f] /@ Join[listxyz, listmn, 2]
(* {f[1, 2, 3, 10, 11], f[4, 5, 6, 12, 13], f[7, 8, 9, 14, 15]} *)
```

*(I used `f` instead of your `func` to show the structure of the result.)*

Or maybe you want all combinations of pairs across both input lists:

```
Apply[f]@*Flatten /@ Tuples[{listxyz, listmn}]
(* {f[1, 2, 3, 10, 11], f[1, 2, 3, 12, 13], f[1, 2, 3, 14, 15], 
    f[4, 5, 6, 10, 11], f[4, 5, 6, 12, 13], f[4, 5, 6, 14, 15], 
    f[7, 8, 9, 10, 11], f[7, 8, 9, 12, 13], f[7, 8, 9, 14, 15]} *)
```

Comment: Thanks, I want to evaluate the function for all possible pairs of values from both lists. Your answer almost gets there by doing this when `len(listxyz) == len(listmn)`. I am interested to see how one could do this when they are not equal :)

Comment: Yes, I anticipated that and had updated my answer.

Answer (score 3):

First, you can use [`Outer`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) together with [`Join`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Join.html) to generate all possible combinations:

```
Outer[Join, listxyz, listmn, 1]
```

Then, you can use [`MapApply`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/MapApply.html) to map your function. However, as `Outer` returned a 2D list, you should [`Catenate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Catenate.html) it first.

```
func @@@ Catenate@Outer[Join, listxyz, listmn, 1]
```

The same approach works also if you have multiple lists. You only have to replace `Catenate` with a more general `Flatten`:

```
func @@@ Flatten[Outer[Join, listr, listxyz, listmn, 1], 2]
```

You can also give a list with just one element, for example:

```
func @@@ Flatten[Outer[Join, {{r}}, listxyz, listmn, 1], 2]
```

Comment: Thanks! This does exactly what I asked for. If one of the entries had to be a symbolic value, what would I have to do? Say, `func[r_,x_,y_,z_,m_,n_]:=(3x+4y+z)/(2m+n)*r` where `r` stays as a symbolic value.

Comment: Please see the last example in the edit. Also note that you will probably get other answers with different approaches. You should take a look at all of them – it will help you learn Mathematica :)

Comment: Thanks! For now, I am looking to solve my problem. I am curious how the language works, so I will also explore other answers!

Comment: Regarding `If one of the entries had to be a symbolic value...`, do you mean you want to add a constraint on the first argument that it must be symbolic, or do you just mean that you have another argument list all of whose elements are symbols? Or do you mean that in `func` the `r` should always be `r`, i.e. callers can never override it?